# I want to search the keys of an array inside my DB

Tags: php, arrays, database, drupal

I have an array in PHP:

```
$my_array = array(
     [6] => blabla6
     [3] => blabla3
     [7] => blabla7
);

$query = db_select('dog', 'dg')
      ->fields('dg')
      ->condition('numbers', array_keys($my_array), 'WHERE IN');
```

I want to get all the rows that have `numbers = "key of the my_array"` and I have no idea how do that thing. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I do not want to use foreach because I don't want to loop that query many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://api.drupal.org/comment/13314#comment-13314) site it should be just:

```
->condition('numbers', array_keys($my_array), 'IN')
```

Answer (score 0):

concatenate your array keys by loop like $str_con_keys=('key1','key2','key3') and place IN like

```
condition('numbers', $str_con_keys, 'IN')
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
$str = "'".implode("'".','."'", array_keys( $my_array ))."'";
// add single quote to each value    

$query = db_select('dog', 'dg')
  ->fields('dg')
  ->condition('numbers', $str, 'IN');
```